# prototypeJS, change the row color Im 'using'

Tags: prototypejs

I'm using prototypeJS and I want to highlight the row of the record I've clicking on...

However, the issue is when I click on a second row, I want the first row to return to its original state - not I get multipls rows highlighted, but I only want the LAST ONE I CLICKED to be highlighted

HTML has a row id - so I know which row Im using.

```
    <tr id="tblRowThing10434" bgcolor="#DDD">
    <td>10434</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td nowrap="">bbb</td>
    <td nowrap=""><input class="btnSubmit" 
                         type="button" 
                         onmousedown="getAvailableResources( 10434, 'test', 'work' );" 
                         value="Pick" 
                         name="pickThing" ></td>
</tr>
<tr id="tblRowThing33434" bgcolor="#FFF">
    <td>33434</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td nowrap="">bbb</td>
    <td nowrap=""><input class="btnSubmit" 
                         type="button" 
                         onmousedown="getAvailableResources( 33434, 'test', 'work' );" 
                         value="Pick" 
                         name="pickThing" ></td>
</tr>
```

SCRIPT looks like this

```
function getAvailableResources( a, b, c ) {
    elem = 'tblRowLoad' + a;
    $( elem ).setStyle({ backgroundColor: '#fff' });

    //other 'work'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can address all of the `<tr>`'s siblings and change all the styles and then change the current row background

So change your javascript function from this

```
function getAvailableResources( a, b, c ) {
    elem = 'tblRowLoad' + a;
    $( elem ).setStyle({ backgroundColor: '#fff' });

    //other 'work'
}
```

to this

```
function getAvailableResources( a, b, c ) {
    elem = 'tblRowLoad' + a;

    $(elem).siblings().invoke('setStyle',{ backgroundColor: '' });
    //reset background color by setting to an empty string ''

    $( elem ).setStyle({ backgroundColor: '#fff' });

    //other 'work'
}
```

Comment: If the alternating stripes are set by the stylesheet instead of overrides on the element itself - reseting the background color to an empty string - or `inherit` will revert it back to the stylesheet style

Comment: ya, but since I'm clicking on a 'different' row - I'll be passing in the new row identifier - no way of knowing which row needs to be changed back to the old style.

Comment: What sets the striping? is is a stylesheet in the header? or is it an style attribute on the element? If you are just using the style attribute you can save the previous background color in `data-*` attributes - I'll edit my answer to illustrate

Comment: to answer your q: I changed the color setting to a class - 'even' or 'odd' - defined in a style block. I can go back to inline 'background-color' if needed. I was experimenting with some other solutions, so it's open to a solution now. the only thing that is a 'limit' is that the data is 'grouped' so I cant just alternate rows, as two adjacent rows "may" have the same color intentionally...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the usage of a simple [css](/questions/tagged/css):

```
.activeRow { background-color:#fff; }
/** in case you are using dirty inline css, add !important here but be ashamed pls */
```

Comebind with some handy features in your [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```
function getAvailableResources( a, b, c ) {
    elem = $('tblRowLoad' + a);

    /** clear all rows */
    elem.siblings().invoke('removeClassName', 'activeRow');
    /** highlight current row */
    elem.addClassName('activeRow');

    //other 'work'
}
```

---

If this doesn't work - *(for example, because you didn't use a class for your background color and can't change this (which you should!))* - add **!important** after the color code (#fff) to the class **.activeRow**.